# How do I debug an Open Shift 503 Service Unavailable error

Tags: openshift

I have a node app that I'm trying to deploy to Open Shift. It's basic express, pretty much vanilla from the express generator. It runs locally. When I push to OpenShift I get the following error:

```
503 Service Unavailable
No server is available to handle this request.
```

Now I'm not surprised there are errors because I've pushed a whole new application on to open shift in one go, but what I want to know is how do I go about finding them?

How do I go about debugging this? How do I crack open the server and see what's going on?

Comment: The 503 message in openshift is absolutely terrible. It could give a message back of: health check failed, or app didn't respond or anything. This issue has been plaguing me for weeks, no way to debug.

Answer (score 9):

You can try the following things:

- `rhc tail <app_name>` to view the log files on the server
- Connect to the server with SSH look at the logs in `~/app-root/logs`
- If this is a scaled application, go to `http://<app_name>-<your_namespace>.rhcloud.com/haproxy-status` to view the status of your scaled gears

Answer (score 2):

I know this is kind of old, but I just had an issue with this 503 error. My log tail showed the app was fine, but the HA Proxy Status link showed the site as being down. I'm running a Node Express app that handles requests to specific endpoints, and I had no handler defined for the root "/" request. I ended up adding

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.status('200').send('Service is up');
});
```

and all is well.

Answer (score 2):

I got stuck on a similar "503 Service Unavailable" today while deploying a Simple Spring Boot app to Minishift (i.e. the local Openshift).

For me the problem was that I did not have an "EXPOSE" line in the Dockerfile that I used to create the Docker image.

I overlooked this at first, but the "oc new-app" command actually hints at this:

```
* The image does not expose any ports - if you want to load balance or send traffic to this component
    you will need to create a service with 'expose dc/sb-test --port=[port]' later
```

Comment: It seems there are lots of situations causing this problem, I've exposed my port but I still have this issue, without any logs.

Answer (score 1):

Consider these items and make sure they are OK:

- The hostname and the URL path were typed correctly, a route matching this hostname exists, and the route was created using the desired path.
- The resources **exposed** by this route (pods, services, deployment configs, etc) have at least one pod running.
- Service selectors match a pod
- Pods are passing the readiness probe so that they won't be removed from the Service endpoint

In one case, I added `router=public` label to my route and changed its TLS settings by adding code below to spec:

```yaml
  tls:
    termination: edge
    insecureEdgeTerminationPolicy: Allow
```

It still can be from other networking or configuration issues that prevented the Service from connecting with the pods.

Reading [this article](https://komodor.com/learn/how-to-fix-kubernetes-service-503-service-unavailable-error/) can be helpful.